# What's difference between UntypedActor and ReceiveActor in Akka.Net?

Tags: c#, akka.net

I'm trying to find differences between UntypedActor and ReceiveActor.
I read documents for both,

https://getakka.net/articles/actors/untyped-actor-api.html

https://getakka.net/articles/actors/receive-actor-api.html

but it seems both provide almost the same features.
how do I select? where should I use them?

Answer (score 4):

with more research, found that ReceiveActor inherits UntypedActor,
and within it, I can declare specific methods to handle without putting everything into OnReceive method, using Receive()

for more details

https://getakka.net/api/Akka.Actor.ReceiveActor.html

Comment: I found your link to the docs and this article [here](https://www.syncfusion.com/succinctly-free-ebooks/akka-net-succinctly/working-with-actors#:~:text=Type%20of%20actors,while%20the%20other%20is%20not.)
helped fill in the gaps I was misunderstanding